# What is easiest way to create a controller/routes/view in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I may be crazy, but I think that I one time saw that you can do the following:

```
create file:  app/controllers/hello_controller.rb
create file:  app/view/hello/foo.html.erb
```

without having to create a change in the routes.rb and a method in hello_controller.rb, I thought that the default mapping of url:
    /hello/foo

would output the foo.html.erb because the '/hello' would know to use the default hello_controller, and the '/foo'  would know to route to action 'foo' and thus map to the view hello/foo.html.erb???

Basically, I am creating some quick static pages and have to put in 4 different changes: controller, action method, routes, and view....is there any way to do this quickly and avoid all the process and just get rails to pick up 'default' controller and view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you would do `rails generate controller hello foo`. This would create a controller called hello with a method called foo.

Comment: so the files have to be there and there is not way to do magic routing, where the files dont exist?  ie. hello_controller.rb not exist?

Comment: When using the above command, it will inject resources :hello into your routes.rb file.